# How to display the value of array as string or text not as index value

Tags: php

I have two table one for sections where each section has many questions when i echo i got the section text but the questions as index value 0 1 2

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ($result) {
    $data = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[($row['SECTION_NAME'])][][($row['QUES_TEXT'])][]  = array(
            'SECTION' => $row['SECTION_NAME'],
            'QUESTION' => $row['QUES_TEXT'] 
        );
    }

    foreach ($data as $SECTION => $QUESTIONS) {
        echo '<h2>',htmlentities($SECTION),'</h2>';

        foreach ($QUESTIONS as $QUESTIONS_TEXT => $TEXT) {
            echo '<h2>',($QUESTIONS_TEXT),'</h2>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP v5.5 and have been removed as of v7.0. They should not be used for new code and should be swapped out for [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) equivalents as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating extra nested arrays and also the parens are unneeded:

```
$data[$row['SECTION_NAME']][][$row['QUES_TEXT']][]  = array(
  'SECTION' => $row['SECTION_NAME'],
  'QUESTION' => $row['QUES_TEXT'] 
);
```

Should be:

```
if (empty($data[$row['SECTION_NAME']]) {
  $data[$row['SECTION_NAME']] = array();
}
$data[$row['SECTION_NAME']][$row['QUES_TEXT']] = array(
    'SECTION' => $row['SECTION_NAME'],
    'QUESTION' => $row['QUES_TEXT'] 
);
```

Also please see the comments to your original question, this is no longer a safe way to use MySQL from PHP.

Comment: I edit my code as echo '<h2>',($TEXT),'</h2>'; but i got array array array